# How to roll a graph on the y-axis

Tags: plotting, matrix, geometry, rotation

I want to roll the function f(x)=sqrt(x), x∈[0,1] along the y-axis.

I know how to rotate the graph around a point, but I'm not sure how to rotate along an axis in 2D.

[image: From here]
[image: To here]

Rotating around a point e.g. (0,0) would look like this:

```
Manipulate[ParametricPlot[{{t, t^(1/2)}, RotationTransform[k, {0, 0}][{t, t^(1/2)}]}, {t, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}], {k, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Rotating the line 3 dimensionally around the axis in 2D?

Comment: It's been a while, so this might be a good time to note that if you roll a (piece of a) parabola over a line, the focus will trace a catenary.

Answer (score 26):

We calculate the tangent vector of parametric curve `{t^2,t}` and the `ArcLength` from `0` to `t0` so that we get the point `{0,s[t0]}` in y-axis.

```
c[t_] = {t^2, t};
s[t_] = ArcLength[c[τ], {τ, 0, t}];
t0 = .6;
Show[ParametricPlot[c[t], {t, 0, 1}, Mesh -> {{t0}}, 
  MeshStyle -> {PointSize[Large], Red}, MeshFunctions -> (#3 &), 
  MeshShading -> {Red, Automatic}], 
 Graphics[{Arrow[{c[t], c[t] + .3 Normalize[c'[t]]}] /. 
    t -> t0, {Arrow[{{0, s[t0]}, {0, s[t0] + .3}}], Thick, Red, 
    PointSize[Large], Point[{0, s[t0]}], 
    Line[{{0, 0}, {0, s[t0]}}]}}], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

After that we translate the curve from `c[t0]` to `{0, s[t0]}` and rotate it around `{0,s[t0]}` so that the tangent vector become the new direction `{0,1}` which toward to the y-axis;

```
c[t_] = {t^2, t};
s[t_] = ArcLength[c[τ], {τ, 0, t}];
r[t_, t0_] := 
  RotationTransform[{c'[t0], {0, 1}}, {0, s[t0]}][
   c[t] + {0, s[t0]} - c[t0]];
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[r[t, t0], {t, 0, 1}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 2}}], {t0, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

## Edition 1

We generalize the idea from above to deal with two parametric curves. Here we use `NDSolve` to handle the re-parametric equation of curve
$$\begin{cases}\frac{\mathrm{d}s}{\mathrm{d}t}=|r'(t)|\\s(0)=0\end{cases}$$

and thanks @Daniel Huber provide `FunctionInterpolation` to increase the speed.

```
r1[t_] = {1.5 + 1.5 Cos[π - t], Sin[π - t]}; t1 = 
 FunctionInterpolation[
   InverseFunction[
     NDSolve[{s1'[t] == Norm[r1'[t]], s1[0] == 0}, 
       s1, {t, 0, 100}][[1, 1, 2]]][x], {x, 0, 50}] // Quiet;
r2[t_] = {t^2, 3 t};
t2 = FunctionInterpolation[
    InverseFunction[
      NDSolve[{s2'[t] == Norm[r2'[t]], s2[0] == 0}, 
        s2, {t, 0, 100}][[1, 1, 2]]][x], {x, 0, 50}] // Quiet;
Animate[Show[ParametricPlot[{r1[t1[s]], r2[t2[s]]}, {s, 0, 20}], 
  Graphics[Arrow[{r1[t1[s]], r1[t1[s]] + D[r1[t1[s]], s]} /. 
     s -> s0]], 
  Graphics[Arrow[{r2[t2[s]], r2[t2[s]] + D[r2[t2[s]], s]} /. 
     s -> s0]]], {s0, 0, 20}, DefaultDuration -> 10]
```

```
r1[t_] = {1.5 + 1.5 Cos[π - t], Sin[π - t]}; t1 = 
 FunctionInterpolation[
   InverseFunction[
     NDSolve[{s1'[t] == Norm[r1'[t]], s1[0] == 0}, 
       s1, {t, 0, 100}][[1, 1, 2]]][x], {x, 0, 50}] // Quiet;
r2[t_] = {t^2, 3 t};
t2 = FunctionInterpolation[
    InverseFunction[
      NDSolve[{s2'[t] == Norm[r2'[t]], s2[0] == 0}, 
        s2, {t, 0, 100}][[1, 1, 2]]][x], {x, 0, 50}] // Quiet;
trans[ss_, ss0_] := 
  RotationTransform[{D[r1[t1[s]], s], D[r2[t2[s]], s]} /. s -> ss0, 
    r2[t2[ss0]]][r1[t1[ss]] + r2[t2[ss0]] - r1[t1[ss0]]];
curves = ParametricPlot[{r1[t1[s]], r2[t2[s]]}, {s, 0, 20}];
Animate[Show[curves, 
  ParametricPlot[trans[ss, ss0], {ss, 0, 3 π}]], {ss0, 0, 20}, 
 DefaultDuration -> 10]
```

## Edition 2

I eventually find out that we need not use `InverseFunction` at all, just use the `NDSolve` since we can rewrite the equation as

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\mathrm{d}s}=\frac{1}{|r'(t)|}$$
that is
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\mathrm{d}s}|r'(t)|=1$$
So we consider the equation

```
t'[s]*Norm[r'[t[s]]] == 1, t[0]==0
```

```
r1[t_] = {1.5 + 1.5 Cos[π - t], Sin[π - t]};
r2[t_] = {t^2, 3 t};
L = 20;
t1 = NDSolve[{t1'[s]*Norm[r1'[t1[s]]] == 1, t1[0] == 0}, 
    t1, {s, 0, L}][[1, 1, 2]];
t2 = NDSolve[{t2'[s]*Norm[r2'[t2[s]]] == 1, t2[0] == 0}, 
    t2, {s, 0, L}][[1, 1, 2]];
trans[s_, s0_] := 
  RotationTransform[{(r1@*t1)'@s0, (r2@*t2)'@s0}, r2@t2@s0][
   r1@t1@s + r2@t2@s0 - r1@t1@s0];
curves = ParametricPlot[{r1@t1@s, r2@t2@s}, {s, 0, L}];
Animate[Show[curves, 
  Graphics[Arrow[{r1@t1@s0, r1@t1@s0 + (r1@*t1)'@s0}]], 
  Graphics[Arrow[{r2@t2@s0, r2@t2@s0 + (r2@*t2)'[s0]}]], 
  ParametricPlot[trans[s, s0], {s, 0, L}], 
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 18}, {-2, 15}}], {s0, 0, L}, 
 DefaultDuration -> 10]
```

[image]

## Edition 3

For several curves.

```
L = 32;
r1[t_] = {1.5 + 1.5 Cos[π - t], Sin[π - t]};
r2[t_] = RotationTransform[{{5, 4}, {0, 1}}]@{5 t, 4 Sin[t]};
r3[t_] = {-t^2, 2 t};
r4[t_] = {5 + 5 Cos[π - t], 4 Sin[π - t]};
{t1, t2, t3, t4} = 
  Module[{t, s}, 
    Function[r, 
     NDSolve[{t'[s]*Norm[r'[t[s]]] == 1, t[0] == 0}, t, {s, 0, L}][[1,
        1, 2]]]] /@ {r1, r2, r3, r4};
{c1, c2, c3, c4} = {r1@*t1, r2@*t2, r3@*t3, r4@*t4};
trans[c2_, c1_][s_, s0_] := 
  RotationTransform[{c1'@s0, c2'@s0}, c2@s0]@
   TranslationTransform[c2@s0 - c1@s0]@c1@s;
Animate[Show[
  ParametricPlot[
   Table[c@s, {c, {c1, c2, c3, c4}}] // Evaluate, {s, 0, L}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Red, Orange, Green, Cyan}], 
  Graphics[{Arrowheads[Medium], 
    Table[Arrow[{c@s0, c@s0 + c'@s0}], {c, {c1, c2, c3, c4}}]}], 
  ParametricPlot[
   Table[trans[c, c1][s, s0], {c, {c2, c3, c4}}] // Evaluate, {s, 0, 
    L}, PlotStyle -> {Orange, Green, Cyan}], 
  PlotRange -> {{-25, 25}, {-8, 20}}, ImageSize -> Large], {s0, 0, L},
  DefaultDuration -> 10]
```

[image]

Comment: `c[t_] = {3 + 3 Cos[π - t], 2 Sin[π - t]}; 
tangent[t_] = FrenetSerretSystem[c[t], t][[2, 1]]; 
s[t_] := NIntegrate[c'[τ] . c'[τ] // Sqrt, {τ, 0, t}]; 
r[t_, t0_] := 
 RotationTransform[{tangent[t0], {0, 1}}, {0, s[t0]}][
  c[t] + {0, s[t0]} - c[t0]]; Animate[
 ParametricPlot[r[t, t0], {t, 0, 2 π}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 8}, {-4, 18}}], {t0, 0, 2 π}, 
 DefaultDuration -> 20]` for another curve.

Comment: thats really well made!

Answer (score 14):

Assuming you mean roll as in the way a circle rolls across the floor, you need a *unit speed arc-length parameterization* of the curve $(t^2,t)$.  Why?  Becuase the key behavior of rolling is *no slippage*.  If a point $(t_0^2,t_0)$ is tangent to the $y$-axis at $(0,l(t_0))$, then the arc length from $(0,0)$ to $(t_0^2,t_0)$ along the curve should be equal to $l(t_0)$.

There's no closed form* for the curve $(\gamma(t)^2,\gamma(t))$ such that $\big(\frac{d\gamma(t)^2}{dt}\big)^2+\big(\frac{d\gamma(t)}{dt}\big)^2=1$ (unit speed).  We can still write it symbolically though

```
DSolve[{1==D[\[Gamma][t]^2,t]^2+D[\[Gamma][t],t]^2,0==\[Gamma][0]},\[Gamma][t],t][[2,1]]
```

We get $\gamma$ is the inverse function of $\frac14\sinh^{-1}(2t)+\frac t2\sqrt{1+4t^2}$.  The angle of $(\gamma(t)^2,\gamma(t))$ is

```
ArcTan[D[\[Gamma][t]^2/.%,t]/D[\[Gamma][t]/.%,t]]/.(\[Gamma][t]/.%)->\[Gamma][t]
```

We get $\tan^{-1}(2\gamma(t))$.  All `Manipulate` needs to do is translate and rotate the curve $(\gamma(t)^2,\gamma(t))$ so that $(\gamma(t_0)^2,\gamma(t_0))$ is tangent to $(0,t_0)$.

```
\[Gamma][t_]=(*thanks to Daniel Huber for FunctionInterpolation, a huge speedup*)
  FunctionInterpolation[InverseFunction[1/4ArcSinh[2#1]+1/2#1Sqrt[1+4#1^2]&][x],{x,0,10}][t];
Manipulate[ParametricPlot[
  {Cos[#2]#[[1]]-Sin[#2]#[[2]],Cos[#2]#[[2]]+Sin[#2]#[[1]]}&
  [{\[Gamma][t]^2,\[Gamma][t]}-{\[Gamma][T]^2,\[Gamma][T]},ArcTan[2\[Gamma][T]]]
  +{0,T},{t,0,10},PlotRange->{{0,10},{0,10}}],{T,0,10}]
```

The fourth line does rotation, the fifth line translates $\gamma$ w.r.t. $(0,0)$, and the last line translates along the $y$-axis.

[image: rolling root]

*closed form meaning 'finite composition of elementary functions'

Comment: To speed it up, try:` \[Gamma][t_] = 
  FunctionInterpolation[
    InverseFunction[1/4 ArcSinh[2 #1] + 1/2 #1 Sqrt[1 + 4 #1^2] &][
     x], {x, 0, 10}][t];`

Comment: *This* is what I was looking for!